# Global Code segment in MVC View giving an error.... "Expression Expected."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a View in which I have a code block where I am setting some variables and later on using those variables to show or hide some areas...

When I build this website. A compilation error comes up on the line `@(` stating `Syntax Error` and another one stating `Expression Expected`. Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong here....

```
@ModelType arwedes.WebShop.Model.Gruppe1Liste
@Code

End Code
@(
    Dim lblInfoTitleText As String = String.Empty
    Dim lblInfoText As String = String.Empty
    Dim panelInfoVisibility As Boolean = False
    Select Case WebSession.Menu
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Home
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.HomeTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Home", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Reservieren
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.ReservierenTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Reservieren", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Kaufen
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.KaufenTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Kaufen", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Verkaufen
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.VerkaufenTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Verkaufen", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Member
            If Request.RawUrl.Contains("login") Then
                lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.MemberTitle", AppSession.Language)
                lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Member", AppSession.Language)
                panelInfoVisibility = True
            End If
    End Select

    Dim bShowCatMenu As Boolean = False
    Select Case WebSession.Menu
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Home
            bShowCatMenu = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Kaufen
            bShowCatMenu = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Reservieren
            bShowCatMenu = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Member
            If Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") = "/membermenu.aspx" Or Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") = "/welcome.aspx" Then
                bShowCatMenu = True
            End If
    End Select
)
@If panelInfoVisibility Then
    @: <div id="panelInfo">
    @: <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 8pt"> <b> <span id="lblInfoTitle">@lblInfoTitleText</span>
    @: </b><br /> <span id="lblInfo">@lblInfoText</span> </p> </div> 
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@ModelType arwedes.WebShop.Model.Gruppe1Liste
@Code
    Dim lblInfoTitleText As String = String.Empty
    Dim lblInfoText As String = String.Empty
    Dim panelInfoVisibility As Boolean = False
    Select Case WebSession.Menu
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Home
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.HomeTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Home", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Reservieren
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.ReservierenTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Reservieren", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Kaufen
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.KaufenTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Kaufen", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Verkaufen
            lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.VerkaufenTitle", AppSession.Language)
            lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Verkaufen", AppSession.Language)
            panelInfoVisibility = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Member
            If Request.RawUrl.Contains("login") Then
                lblInfoTitleText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.MemberTitle", AppSession.Language)
                lblInfoText = arwedes.WebShop.Model.Text.GetText("Info.Member", AppSession.Language)
                panelInfoVisibility = True
            End If
    End Select

    Dim bShowCatMenu As Boolean = False
    Select Case WebSession.Menu
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Home
            bShowCatMenu = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Kaufen
            bShowCatMenu = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Reservieren
            bShowCatMenu = True
        Case arwedes.WebShop.Web.Navigation.MenuEnum.Member
            If Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") = "/membermenu.aspx" Or Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") = "/welcome.aspx" Then
                bShowCatMenu = True
            End If
    End Select
End Code
@If panelInfoVisibility Then
    @: <div id="panelInfo">
    @: <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 8pt"> <b> <span id="lblInfoTitle">@lblInfoTitleText</span>
    @: </b><br /> <span id="lblInfo">@lblInfoText</span> </p> </div> 
End If
```

This being said, code like the one you wrote doesn't belong to a view. So the real solution to your problem would be to externalize it (helper, view model?).

Can you ever imagine giving your views to a web designer? He will scream out in despair.

Comment: I would move the logic up at least to the controller level or even "higher" to some site map or navigation service. The point is that logic should be implemented in "proper" classes that can be e.g. unit tested easily. The view should just get those values pushed from the controller (infotitle, infotext, ispanelvisible showcatmenu, etc.) and not "calculate".

Comment: @Tz_, totally agree with you, this logic absolutely doesn't belong to a view.

Comment: Thanks Darin for the answer and thanks to @Tz_ for pointing in the right direction. I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `@( ...)` put your code inside the `@Code ... End Code` block.